# android compose navigation: dialog destination automatically popped when app is minimized

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

below is a part of my code, [(full code can be found here)](https://github.com/MohammadMD1383/Vault/blob/1f47da730239bbbb9ab00478467bb0e1e306082f/app/src/main/java/ir/mmd/androidDev/vault/MainActivity.kt#L111-L165).

The problem is that the destination `content/{mode}` *(last destination)* is automatically popped, when app gets minimized.

What should I do to prevent this?

```
    Surface(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = if (AppSettings.authenticationEnabled) "welcome" else "home") {
            composable(
                route = "welcome",
                enterTransition = { fadeIn() },
                exitTransition = { fadeOut() }
            ) { WelcomePage(navController) }
            
            composable(
                route = "home",
                enterTransition = {
                    when (initialState.destination.route) {
                        "welcome" -> fadeIn()
                        "settings" -> slideInHorizontally { if (rtl) -it else it }
                        else -> null
                    }
                },
                exitTransition = {
                    when (targetState.destination.route) {
                        "welcome" -> fadeOut()
                        "settings" -> slideOutHorizontally { if (rtl) -it else it }
                        else -> null
                    }
                }
            ) { HomePage(navController, items/* todo */) }
            
            composable(
                route = "settings",
                enterTransition = {
                    when (initialState.destination.route) {
                        "welcome" -> fadeIn()
                        "home" -> slideInHorizontally { if (rtl) it else -it }
                        else -> null
                    }
                },
                exitTransition = {
                    when (targetState.destination.route) {
                        "welcome" -> fadeOut()
                        "home" -> slideOutHorizontally { if (rtl) it else -it }
                        else -> null
                    }
                }
            ) { SettingsPage(navController) }
            
            dialog( // <--- problem is here
                route = "content/{mode}",
                dialogProperties = DialogProperties(
                    dismissOnBackPress = false,
                    dismissOnClickOutside = false,
                    decorFitsSystemWindows = false,
                    usePlatformDefaultWidth = false
                )
            ) { ContentPage(navController) }
        }
    }
```

#### What I have done before?

I have searched the internet, but this seems to be a new concept that hasn't been asked by anyone else before, as far as I can see...

Comment: What version of Navigation are you using?

Comment: @ianhanniballake the current latest version, 2.7.3